# Как сделать так, что бы call.data менялась после каждой новой inline-клавиатуры

Tags: python, telebot

помогите сделать так, чтобы call.data  принимала новое значение при каждом вызове inline-клавиатуры:

```
import telebot
from keyboa import keyboa_maker

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')

answers1 = ['Домашнюю']
answers2 = ['Алгебра', 'Геометрия']
answers3 = ['На завтра', 'На после завтра']
answers4 = ['1', '2']
kb_1 = keyboa_maker(items=answers1, copy_text_to_callback=True)
kb_2 = keyboa_maker(items=answers2, copy_text_to_callback=True)
kb_3 = keyboa_maker(items=answers3, copy_text_to_callback=True)
kb_4 = keyboa_maker(items=answers4, copy_text_to_callback=True)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Привет, это Бот-песочница Глеба, можешь по пользоваться, скоро будем тут тестировать технологии')
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_1,
        text="Что хотим узнать???")


    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def send_text(call):
    if call.data == 'Домашнюю':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_4, text="Какая подгруппа?")
    if call.data == '1':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_2, text="По какому предмету?")
    if call.data == 'Алгебра':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_3, text="На какой день?")
    if call.data == 'Геометрия':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_3, text="На какой день?")
    if call.data == 'На завтра':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Первая подгруппа дз по геометрии на завтра")
    elif call.data == 'На после завтра':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Первая подгруппа дз по геометрии на после завтра")
    if call.data == 'На завтра':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Первая подгруппа дз по алгебре на завтра")
    elif call.data == 'На после завтра':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Первая подгруппа дз по алгебре на после завтра")
    if call.data == '2':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_2, text="По какому предмету?")
```

Comment: Что вам конкретно надо?

Answer (score 0):

Первое замечание, нельзя так делать:

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def send_text(call):
    if call.data == 'Домашнюю':
        print(call.data) # PRINT ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ, ЧТО В CALL.DATA ЛЕЖИТ 
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_4, text="Какая подгруппа?")
        print(call.data) # И ПОСЛЕ ВЫЗОВА ВТОРОЙ КЛАВИАТУРЫ PRINT ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ, ЧТО В CALL.DATA ЛЕЖИТ 'Домашнюю'
        if call.data == '1':
        .
        .
        .
```

Лучше замените на это:

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def send_text(call):
    if call.data == 'Домашнюю':
        print(call.data) # PRINT ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ, ЧТО В CALL.DATA ЛЕЖИТ 
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_4, text="Какая подгруппа?")
        print(call.data) # И ПОСЛЕ ВЫЗОВА ВТОРОЙ КЛАВИАТУРЫ PRINT ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ, ЧТО В CALL.DATA ЛЕЖИТ 'Домашнюю'
    if call.data == '1':
        .
        .
        .
```

(Если не заметили, то говорю что `if` в другой `if` нельзя засовывать, если логично подумать то второй `if` никогда не сработает)
Вот сам исправлений код:

```py
#coding: cp1251
import telebot
from keyboa import keyboa_maker

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1575682797:AAHU1D3mn8iDd8z1JC_3dTa1SVcwMo-lwkc')

answers1 = ['Домашнюю']
answers2 = ['Алгебра', 'Геометрия']
answers3 = ['На завтра', 'На после завтра']
answers4 = ['1', '2']
kb_1 = keyboa_maker(items=answers1, copy_text_to_callback=True)
kb_2 = keyboa_maker(items=answers2, copy_text_to_callback=True)
kb_3 = keyboa_maker(items=answers3, copy_text_to_callback=True)
kb_4 = keyboa_maker(items=answers4, copy_text_to_callback=True)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Привет, это Бот-песочница Глеба, можешь по пользоваться, скоро будем тут тестировать технологии')
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_1,
        text="Что хотим узнать???")


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def send_text(call):
    if call.data == 'Домашнюю':
        print(call.data) # PRINT ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ, ЧТО В CALL.DATA ЛЕЖИТ 
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_4, text="Какая подгруппа?")
        print(call.data) # И ПОСЛЕ ВЫЗОВА ВТОРОЙ КЛАВИАТУРЫ PRINT ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ, ЧТО В CALL.DATA ЛЕЖИТ 'Домашнюю'
    if call.data == '1':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_2, text="По какому предмету?")
    if call.data == 'Алгебра':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_3, text="На какой день?")
    if call.data == 'На завтра':
        print("Первая подгруппа дз по алгебре на завтра")
    if call.data == 'На после завтра':
        print("Первая подгруппа дз по алгебре на после завтра")

    if call.data == 'Геометрия':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_3, text="На какой день?")
    if call.data == '2':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_2, text="По какому предмету?")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Понял ошибку, но у вас ветка   геометрии не работает, выводит везде только алгебру

Comment: Понял вас, потому-что там стоит `elif` и он возможно и мешает. Щас исправлю.
В чем собственно ошибка у вас была?

Comment: Я исправил код в вопросе. Суть такая: если пройти по этим условиям и выбрать геометрию, то помимо нее выводится еще и алгебра, все перепробовал чтобы это исправить (с алгеброй все норм)